# borderlayout in swt or swing

Tags: java, swing, layout, swt, border-layout

I want to arrange components as shown in image. I can do this by using gridbaglayout but I want to do this using borderlayout. I tried it but could not achieve what I wanted. so please guide me here.
The black rectangles here are components like JPanel, Button etc.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do it only with BorderLayout, you need to use 2 BorderLayout. If you cannot use 2 layouts, then you are stuck with GridBagLayout.
This is a demonstration of what I am telling:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {

    protected void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel2.add(new JButton("NORTH"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel2.add(new JButton("CENTER"));
        panel.add(panel2);
        panel.add(new JButton("SOUTH"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        panel.add(new JButton("EAST"), BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test().initUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: @Guillaume Polet: Thanks for this nice example.

Answer (score 3):

Border layout doesn't work that way.  This is the border layout schematic:

[image]

You will not be able to place the EAST layout into the top right-hand corner - NORTH will always float to the right hand side.

Edit: shows how long it's been since I used Swing or AWT - back when I did, it was EAST, NORTH, WEST, SOUTH and CENTER.

Comment: EAST, NORTH, WEST, SOUTH and CENTER are still valid

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : They are valid, though the [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) discourage their use now since Java 1.4, by stating "Before JDK release 1.4, the preferred names for the various areas were different, ranging from points of the compass (for example, BorderLayout.NORTH for the top area) to wordier versions of the constants we use in our examples. The constants our examples use are preferred because they are standard and enable programs to adjust to languages that have different orientations."